# INDEX/MATCH to return value that is less than or equal to range in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I am trying to get excel to look through collected data and return a work time that matches closest to the input values.

What I have right now is:

```
=INDEX(F3:F23,MATCH(1,(L6=A3:A23)*(L5=E3:E23)*(L4=B3:B23)*(L3=D3:D23)*(L2=C3:C23),1))
```

but it returns 37.5 no matter what I change the inputs to. With the current inputs I would expect it to return a value of 6.5 from F10. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you provide your sample data as text within your question (using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)) it is much easier to help you.

Comment: You might want to adjust the equations, rather than putting the criteriumtype to 1, i.e. `(L6<=A3:A23)`.

Comment: Oh, when expecting 6,5 you probably meant `(L6>=A3:A23)`, right?

Comment: @Notus_Panda For some reason I still get a return of 37.5 even when adjusting to this I appreciate the help though

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: sorting according to comment**
Bear with me on this one as I'm super stoked that I figured this one out, so I might explain it poorly. It's very likely that others can shorten this btw, this is just my attempt at more complex formulas.

I used:

- `LET` to keep things organized a bit
- `SORTBY` to sort in the manner you explained in the comment on this answer
- A few `DROP(TAKE())` to get the correct columns to compare to in the sorted array (I don't know how to handle this differently yet)
- `FILTER` to finally filter according to the input-criteria
- `TAKE(DROP())` on the filtered result to get the F-column's value

All together that gives:

```
=LET(sorted,SORTBY(A3:F23,E3:E23,-1,A3:A23,-1,D3:D23,-1,C3:C23,-1,B3:B23,-1),h,TAKE(sorted,,1),r,DROP(TAKE(sorted,,2),,1),a,DROP(TAKE(sorted,,3),,2),s,DROP(TAKE(sorted,,4),,3),c,DROP(TAKE(sorted,,5),,4),TAKE(DROP(FILTER(sorted,(L6>=h)*(L5>=c)*(L4>=r)*(L3>=s)*(L2>=a)),,5),1))
```

With result (notice I edited row 11 to show you that it takes the correct one here):
[image]

**OLD:**
As mentioned in the comments:

`=INDEX(F3:F23,MATCH(1,(L6>=A3:A23)*(L5>=E3:E23)*(L4>=B3:B23)*(L3>=D3:D23)*(L2>=C3:C23),0))`

[image]

Comment: Forgot to re-edit the criteriatype, my bad. Thought it was easier copying your formula and editing from there than re-translating from my test-version.

Comment: will this return the value that closest matches my inputs even if the inputs are changed? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It will go for the first found result that is found, i.e. if row 11 would be 59|1|64,3|70,2|3|5,5 it would still go for the 6,5 on row 10 because it was the first found. Is that an issue?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get it to return the closest result to what the inputs are. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, but what weighs more? If for example the hardness is closer for one but the ambient is closer for the other, which one would you go for?

Comment: Catalyst% would be weighed the highest followed by hardness then sand temp, ambient temp and lastly resin%.

Comment: See my edit, I'm quite happy I got it to work ^^

Comment: Wow that's awesome! Thank you so much for all your help I'm not super experienced with excel and this helped me a ton. Thank you thank you.